# Написать и вызвать функцию с переменным количеством параметров

Tags: c++, c, math

Задача есть, нужно отдельно задать функцию со сменным числом параметров, а потом ее вызвать.

Задача на нахождение минимального или максимального значения

```
float min(int k . . .)
```

была проблема в этой штуке, она нужна обязательно в первой функцией, я на очень знаю с++, и непонятно как с ней работать дальше.

Comment: Так с или плюсы? Это важно.

Comment: Желательно с++ но можно на си ибо уже много облазил, не могу ее сделать

Comment: @pavel это не важно, так как ТС не хочет читать учебник, а хочет готовый результат.

Comment: [вот для си](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdarg/va_start/), [вот для плюсов](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/parameter_pack).

Comment: Да ибо не могу найти примера такой задачи, я хз как ввести в 
float min(int k . . .) рандомное кол во значений, а потом найти с них минимальное значение или максимальное

Comment: Не к ТС! Люди, это какой-то кошмар - решил посмотреть в Гугле, первые несколько ссылок - работа через указатели в стек, `stdarg` практически не рассматривается! куда катится этот мир... К автору вопроса - см., например, http://www.c-cpp.ru/content/vastart-vaend-vaarg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#include <utility>
#include <type_traits>
#include <initializer_list>
#include <algorithm>

template<class Head, class... Tail>
constexpr std::common_type_t<Head, Tail...> variadic_min(const Head& head, const Tail&... tail){
    using common_type = std::common_type_t<Head, Tail...>;
    common_type retval = head;
    std::initializer_list<common_type> unused = {retval = std::min(retval, static_cast<common_type>(tail))...};
    return retval;
}

constexpr auto foo(){
    return variadic_min(1, 1.9, -2, 6, -4.3);
}

static_assert(foo() == -4.3, "");
```

Comment: Виктор, решили показать как Вы знаете Си++? Понятно же, что автор не понимает язык, а вы такую простую задачу решаете таким сложным способом. К чему все это?!

Comment: @rudolfninja это самый простой способ решения задачи на C++,  за исключением передачи массива в качестве аргумента (С-стиль в данном случае не проходит, т.к. для него нужно как-то указывать типы аргументов, да и в целом он не для таких задач). Единственное, что здесь можно убрать - это std::common_type_t. В С++17 можно сделать немного проще, но я сомневаюсь, что у автора стоит компилятор с C++17.

Comment: Ну, вообще то он у меня и стоит, а способ и вправду сложный, но все же спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

В С++ есть 3 способа написания функций с переменным числом параметров:

- с использованием *шаблона с переменным количеством аргументов* (пример в ответе выше);
- с использованием библиотечного класса `initializer_list`, для случая, если все параметры имеют одинаковый тип;
- с использованием `varargs` (в стиле Си).

Вот как реализуется вариант с использованием `initializer_list`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <initializer_list>

float min(std::initializer_list<float> ld)
{
    if (ld.size() == 0) {
        throw std::invalid_argument("Arguments list is empty!");
    }

    float ret;

    for (auto beg = ld.begin(); beg != ld.end(); ++beg) {
        if (beg == ld.begin()) {
           ret = *beg;
        } else if (ret > *beg) {
            ret = *beg;
        }
    }

    return ret;
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << min({4.5, -6, 3.14}) << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```